# How do I commit my code to github via gitbash?

Tags: github, git-bash, git-commit, git-push

When I try to do so I face the below issue

[image]

Comment: So did you think to actually *try* those `git config` commands that it suggested may fix your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your response! You mean I should config using the git config command

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must configure **user email** and **user name** according your github account.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm new to this can you please guide me on how to do that

Comment: 1. Open the command line.
2. Set your username:
    ```git config --global user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME"```
3. Set your email address:
    ```git config --global user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"```